# program to print the largest sum of digits

Tags: variable-assignment

Write a C program that asks the user to enter integers until the value -1 is entered.  Your program should then print the number the user has entered which has the largest sum of digit
 Help please, specially in the last part?

Comment: what did you try so far?

Comment: @aemyl i pretty much did the whole thing, i just don’t know how to get the greatest sum?

Comment: Can you please show your code to provide a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?